# OnClick event for div inside lots of container Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have an app I'm developing and I need a `onclick()` event to be fired when a `<div>` is clicked.

So in other words,

```
<div id="panda"></div>

 $("#panda").click(function () {
        console.log("some text");
    });
```

So this statement works but now lets say I have,

```
    <div id="panda">
    <lots of children>
     <div id="koala">
    </div>
    </lots of children>
    </div>


 $("#koala").click(function () {
        console.log("doesnt work");
    });
```

Now you see for the life of me I can't get koala to be clickable. The click event on parents works fine, and click evens for some empty divs I use as buttons work fine, but for some reason I cant get I filled child `<div>` to be clickable.

Any ideas what the case could be?

I tried this,

```
 $('#panda').click(function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('#koala'))
        {
            console.log("koala");
        }

    });
```

But it just logs every click on the parent.

Comment: `#koala` is a unique ID, right? That is to say, there should be only one element in the whole document with that ID.

Comment: Your try works fine for me - **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/63n0ptch/1)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to listen to the `div` children for `panda`.

```js
$("#panda").on('click','div',function() {
  console.log($(this).text()+' '+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panda">
    <div id="koala">
      koala
    </div>
  <div id="bear">
      bear
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the selector '#panda #koala' like this

```
$("#panda #koala").click(function () {
        console.log("koala");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example,

```
<div id="panda">Panda
    <div id="koala">Koala</div>
</div>

$("#panda").on('click', '#koala', function () {
    alert("koala!!!");
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fk9fLeqq/2/)